# Iterate through JSON files and obtain specific data

Tags: json, powershell, loops, get-childitem

I'm trying to filter through some sign in log data in JSON format within files.

I've got a directory containing the files here:

[image]

Inside these files, is data looking like this:

[image]

What I need to do is go through each file and get specific data, for example.. Return me all data where location is not AU.

Now what I've got technically works, which is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp\sign_in_logs' -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object {$_.Location -ne 'AU'}}
```

But my problem is it prints the entire content of the JSON file where the data I'm looking for is.

My question is, how can I get just the single entry/entries back, which in the case of my example would be just this (get me data where location is not AU):

```
    {
    "id":  "bedf8559-403f-4aa7-b3da-4d5091da8400",
    "createdDateTime":  "2022-03-23T00:44:27Z",
    "userPrincipalName":  "user@domainone",
    "Location":  "CA",
    "ipAddress":  "2.2.2.2",
    "appDisplayName":  "Azure Portal",
    "conditionalAccessStatus":  "success",
    "Status":  "Other."
}
```

Do I need to do something with the data first before I can individually grab the items?

Comment: Your code looks fine, I'm guessing you want to know how to convert the filtered objects back to JSON?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Thanks for responding. Yea so I guess going back to JSON is not important but if that would be the best way or only way of getting only the select data back, I've got no objections

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking to either know how to export the filtered data to different JSON files, or to have the filtered objects in memory but in a way you can identify the source of data.

- If you want to export the filtered JSONs to separated files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp\sign_in_logs' -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
    $fileName = 'filtered_{0}.json' -f $_.BaseName
    Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json |
        Where-Object { $_.Location -ne 'AU' } |
        ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $fileName
}
```

- If you want to have the filtered data in memory:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp\sign_in_logs' -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
    $filtered = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json |
        Where-Object { $_.Location -ne 'AU' }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        SourceFile      = $_.Name
        FilteredObjects = $filtered
    }
}
```

Following above code, you can inspect the `$result` object by filtering techniques and dot notation, i.e.: if you want to see the filtered contents of `one.json`:

```
$result.where{ $_.SourceFile -eq 'one.json' }.FilteredObjects
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I've run your second method but unfortunately the results I'm getting are still my initial results where it's printing the content of the entire .JSON where there is another location present other than AU

Comment: @Secretsec I thought you were looking for all objects where `Location` is not AU since in your code you have `$_.Location -ne 'AU'` if you want the objects where location is AU then you should use `-eq` instead of `-ne`

Comment: Sorry you're correct. I meant: 

"The results I'm getting are still my initial results where it's printing the content of the entire .JSON file INCLUDING AU (which is not what I'm after)".

So in essence, it's printing me all the contents of the file where my query matches. But I only want to see the select entries returned, in this case, just the JSON block where location is CA

Comment: @Secretsec I don't see anything wrong with my code or yours, both look good unless the JSON you have posted is different from the ones you are using this code for